# If $(a)+(b)$ is a principal ideal then $(a)\cap(b)$ is also a principal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Suppose $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $a,b \in R$. I have to show if $(a)+(b)$ is a principal ideal then $(a)\cap(b)$ is also a principal ideal.

Suppose $(a)+(b)=(d)$ for some $d \in R$. Then let $a=pd,b=qd$ and $(a+b)=rd$ for some $p,q,r \in R$. I want to show that $(a)\cap(b)=(pqd)$. Clearly $(pqd)\subset (a)\cap(b)$. How do I prove the converse ?

Comment: I don't think you're using the definition of an ideal addition. $I+J=\{pi+qj: i\in I, j\in J, p,q\in R\}$.

Comment: Why would you want to consider $(a+b)=rd$?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot.